# How to auto update many descendants forms after ancerstor form had an control deleted?

Tags: delphi, visual-inheritance

Suppose a `TAncestorForm` with an extra button (or any other control). If I remove the button, whenever I open a descendant of `TAncestorForm` the Delphi IDE shows a message "Ancestor component not found..." and let me choose:

- Remove the reference;
- Tell that the component was renamed and what is
  it's new name;
- Recreate the component;

I want the first option. There is any other option that would do this automatically instead of opening all descendants (like dozens of them) and clicking in each message?

Comment: Write a script to do the work for you

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Which scripting framework do you have in mind?

Comment: @MartynA Anything you fancy. I personally would use a crude regex in Python.

Comment: You could use [DFMCheck](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/ide-tools/dfmcheck/) to get all forms opened and closed automatically. You'd still have to click the Remove button for each affected form, though.

Comment: Perhaps an AHK script could do the remove button pressing automatically

Comment: @DavidHeffernan So, I think the short answer is "no", but long answer is "maybe, if you do forge one tool for you"?

Comment: @UliGerhardt Yes. But I was thinking on anything that really avoided the clicking annoyance.

Comment: @EmBarbosa I'm sure AHK can do the clicking for you

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, got that. Thank you. But I was thinking on how to propose an answer to this question on SO's guidelines that could be useful to further readers. (:

Comment: I'm not sure that this question is going to be useful to many others

Comment: And let this be a lesson as to one of the reasons form inheritance is not quite as cool as it first appears.